# How to get an iPad to switch automatically to the strongest network?

Tags: ipad, network, wifi

I work in an office that has 3 WiFi networks, the strength obviously depending on where you are in the building. All 3 networks have been set up on my iPad 3. I often move around in the office, but find that my iPad never switches to the strongest network, but always stays on the network I have manually selected (assuming there is even a slight signal of that network). I have to manually go to the Settings app to switch over to the strongest network, which is a hassle.

Is there a way to get the iPad to switch automatically to the currently strongest network?

Comment: The only way this would happen is if you completely lost connection to the one you were currently on.

Comment: So, in other words, I should accept having a very poor connection and slow internet speed when a strong connection in my vicinity is available.

Comment: No go to your settings and switch to a different network. Do you have any device that will switch to a stronger signal? How would it know to switch? What's the threshold? How would it know when not to switch? Etc. I don't think it'd be impossible to do but the amount of time and effort someone would have to put into something like this probably isn't worth the limited application.

Comment: Hi Tony, all good points thanks. However I definitely think there is a need for such an application, seeing though we depend so heavily on a stable and fast internet connection.

Comment: If the office wifi were set up so that they all broadcasted the same SSID (instead of broadcasting different ones) the iPad would automatically use the strongest one.

Comment: → Alan: you are right. I made tests with the original 802.11b (11 Mbit/s) with the same network name on 4 overlaping AirPort Base stations. The access point change was regular and I just noticed normal slow down of my ftp transfer when I was at the equilibrium point between 2 access points.

Comment: → Alan: you have the right answer to this known problem ⇒ please write it.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry mate, unfortunately no such thing exists.

Comment: → Can: shouldn't you make a small test to check ?

Comment: Well that’s a shame. There are apps on android that do exactly what’s requested here. I use SmartWifiSelector, and it works great.